# Getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' (web-scraping)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

This is my case study about web scraping.
I got a problem in the final code  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' so I tried to fix it with 'getattr' function but it didn't work.

'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.birdsnest.com.au/womens/dresses'

source = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')
```

'''

```
productlist= soup.find_all('div', id='items')
```

'''

```
productlinks = []
for item in productlist:
  for link in item.find_all('a',href=True):
      productlinks.append(url + link['href'])
print(len(productlinks))
```

'''

```
productlinks = []
for x in range(1,28):
  source = requests.get(f'https://www.birdsnest.com.au/womens/dresses?_lh=1&page={x}')
  soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')
  for item in productlist:
      for link in item.find_all('a',href=True):
        productlinks.append(url + link['href'])
print(productlinks)
```

'''

```
for link in productlinks:
    source = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')

    name = soup.find('h1',class_='item-heading__name').text.strip()
    price = soup.find('p',class_='item-heading__price').text.strip()
    feature = soup.find('div',class_='tab-accordion__content active').text.strip()

    sum = {
      'name':name,
      'price':price,
      'feature':feature
          }
    print(sum)
```

'''

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d4d46558690d> in <module>()
      3     soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')
      4 
----> 5     name = soup.find('h1',class_='item-heading__name').text.strip()
      6     price = soup.find('p',class_='item-heading__price').text.strip()
      7     feature = soup.find('div',class_='tab-accordion__content active').text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I tried to fix with this method, but it didn't work.

```
 for link in productlinks:
    source = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')

    name = getattr(soup.find('h1',class_='item-heading__name'),'text',None)
    price = getattr(soup.find('p',class_='item-heading__price'),'text',None)
    feature = getattr(soup.find('div',class_='tab-accordion__content active'),'text',None)

    sum = {
      'name':name,
      'price':price,
      'feature':feature
          }
    print(sum)
```

This is the output. It show only 'Nonetype'

```
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
{'name': None, 'price': None, 'feature': None}
```

Comment: This is the first link in `productlinks`: https://www.birdsnest.com.au/womens/dresses/brands/honeysuckle-beach/91043-prissy-dress#Twilnavy And this link is blocked.

Comment: well if you go to one of your links in productlinks list they direct to an empty page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, always turn `JS` off for the page you're scraping. Then you'll realize that tag classes change and these are the ones you want to target.

Also, when looping through the pages, don't forget that Python's `range()` stop value is not inclusive. Meaning, this `range(1, 28)` will stop on page `27`.

Here's how I would go about it:

```
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


cookies = {
    "ServerID": "1033",
    "__zlcmid": "10tjXhWpDJVkUQL",
}

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36"
}


def extract_info(bs: BeautifulSoup, tag: str, attr_value: str) -> list:
    return [i.text.strip() for i in bs.find_all(tag, {"itemprop": attr_value})]


all_pages = []
for page in range(1, 29):
    print(f"Scraping data from page {page}...")

    current_page = f"https://www.birdsnest.com.au/womens/dresses?page={page}"
    source = requests.get(current_page, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')

    brand = extract_info(soup, tag="strong", attr_value="brand")
    name = extract_info(soup, tag="h2", attr_value="name")
    price = extract_info(soup, tag="span", attr_value="price")

    all_pages.extend(
        [
            {
                "brand": b,
                "name": n,
                "price": p,
            } for b, n, p in zip(brand, name, price)
        ]
    )

print(f"{all_pages}\nFound: {len(all_pages)} dresses.")

with open("all_the_dresses2.json", "w") as jf:
    json.dump(all_pages, jf, indent=4)
```

This gets you a `JSON` with all the dresses.

```
    {
        "brand": "boho bird",
        "name": "Prissy Dress",
        "price": "$189.95"
    },
    {
        "brand": "boho bird",
        "name": "Dandelion Dress",
        "price": "$139.95"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Lula Soul",
        "name": "Dandelion Dress",
        "price": "$179.95"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Honeysuckle Beach",
        "name": "Cotton V-Neck A-Line Splice Dress",
        "price": "$149.95"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Honeysuckle Beach",
        "name": "Lenny Pinafore",
        "price": "$139.95"
    },
and so on for the next 28 pages ...
```

Comment: These is my output ,I use all of your code {Scraping data from page 1...
Scraping data from page 2...
Scraping data from page 3...
Scraping data from page 4...
Scraping data from page 5...
Scraping data from page 6...
Scraping data from page 7...}

Comment: Well... the output is going to be in a `JSON` file once the script finishes. This is the line that saves the output to a file `open("all_the_dresses2.json", "w")`

Comment: Oh, I see, you're on Google Colab. I know nothing about it but you can add this line `print(f"{all_pages}\nFound: {len(all_pages)} dresses.")` to print the results.

Comment: OMG! It works. Thanks a million for your help. I try to fix it for many time. Thank you

Comment: If I want to drag the data inside each dress what should I do